# Routing node.js requests via apache mod_proxy: performance?

Tags: ajax, apache, rest, node.js, xss

I'm looking at running a webserver serving webpage content using PHP, and serving REST API requests for AJAX via node.js; node will be running on a different port on the machine, so to get around the issues of XSS restrictions, I'm considering using mod_proxy on Apache to reroute the REST requests to the node port, as described [here](http://stuff.blat.co.za/2011/06/07/bypassing-xss-security-limitations-for-ajax-calls/).

My question is, does this architecture run the risk of degrading performance badly?  I know node.js outperforms Apache considerably in some situations, so my concern is that running these requests through Apache via mod_proxy may slow down the node performance considerably; on the other hand, since it's a straightforward proxying, there may be minimal interference from Apache.

Can I expect that this configuration will reduce my node.js throughput to Apache levels, or is there nothing to worry about?  If this is a performance concern, is there a better way to route / proxy these calls transparently?

Comment: Putting apache infront of node feels really backwards. Put nginx in front of apache & node or just drop apache

Comment: @Raynos: I don't want to drop apache, as it's serving up my PHP quite nicely as is; but nginx sounds tempting.

Comment: Homework?  Certainly seems like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, does this architecture run the risk of degrading
>   performance badly?

I think this depends on the kind of application you are wrote in node.js. If you have long-running requests I think the performance will be pretty bad, because Apache use one thread per connection(NGinx performs much better). If you have short-living connections I think your performance might be acceptable.

My advice would be to benchmark your stack with [siege](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/421). First just benchmark node.js, next behind Apache(proxy).

> @Raynos: I don't want to drop apache, as it's serving up my PHP quite
>   nicely as is; but nginx sounds tempting.

[Nginx can serve PHP](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian) also so maybe you should have a look at Nginx.